# Can't send email with Thunderbird and Gmail

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, gmail

I configured my Gmail account in Ubuntu 14.04 with Thunderbird. I only can receive mail but cannot send it.

I am looking for a solution but with basic configuration it is not possible.

Version of Thunderbird is 32.0.

Comment: Are you using POP3 or IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

You must put in coniguration SMTP

- server SMTP Gmail: smtp.gmail.com
- User SMTP Gmail: your adress Gmail
- Password SMTP Gmail: Your password
- Port SMTP Gmail: 465 (encryption "SSL")
- (SMTP) requiert une authentifications